# hold package and automatically hold dependancies used by the package

Tags: package-management

[How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) shows me how to hold a specific package. But how can I hold a package including all its dependancies. Well, just holding a package wont help, because if the dependancies are upgraded, then the package might wont start at all. So, is there a way, that the package dependancies or to keep it simple, immediate dependacies are also held .

It looks like, that it could be the whole system that would be put to hold this way and this kind of algorithm can be very complex, but maybe its possible and hence the question.

Concrete its related to firefox and thunderbird. Currently the revision is 55 and from version 57, as per the firefox blogs, the addons system would be completely changed. Since, many addons will fail, I wanted to hold the packages and their dependancies firefox and thunderbird forever.

I did

```
sudo apt-mark hold firefox
sudo apt-mark hold thunderbird
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

just shows firefox and thunderbird and not their dependancies.

Comment: Putting the package on hold should also put the dependencies on hold.

If you have a specific problem with a specific package or specific dependency post details.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen updated my post.

Comment: Do you have an example of some dependency being updated or breakage of firefox / thunderbird ? As I said, marking those packages on hold should be sufficient to cover dependencies as well.